# Чем инверсия управления (Inversion of Control, IoC) отличается от инверсии зависимостей (Dependency Inversion Principle, DIP)?

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

В литературе встречаются два разных понятия [Инверсия управления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) и [Принцип инверсии зависимостей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9), которые сформулированы одинакаво:

- Модули верхних уровней не должны зависеть от модулей нижних уровней. Оба типа модулей должны зависеть от абстракций.
- Абстракции не должны зависеть от деталей. Детали должны зависеть от абстракций.

В чем состоит разница?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Inversion of Control** -- это общий термин, который характеризует архитектуру ПО. Применяется обычно к фреймворкам -- инверсия управления является одной из характеристик.

Фреймворки предоставляют точки подключения, в которых вы можете писать свой код. Но при этом общим выполнением программы по-прежнему управляет фреймворк, время от времени вызывая ваш код. Инверсия заключается в том, что в отличии от традиционного подхода не вы вызываете библиотечный код, а библиотечный код вызывает вас. Примерами могут являться ASP.NET и WPF с их событиями.

При этом принцип инверсии управления может использоваться и в более мелком масштабе. Например, есть слой логики (BLL) и доступа к данным (DAL). Общеизвестно, что DAL не может обращаться к BLL. Но иногда возникает потребность на уровне DAL выполнить некий код, который должен принадлежать к BLL. В таком случае в DAL заводится некоторый интерфейс, этот интерфейс реализуется на уровне BLL, и экземпляр конкретной реализации передается из BLL в DAL. Такой пример, в частности, согласуется с DIP.

**Dependency Inversion Principle** дает рекомендации о том, какими должны быть зависимости. Это как раз то, что вы процитировали:

- Модули верхних уровней не должны зависеть от модулей нижних уровней.
  Оба типа модулей должны зависеть от абстракций.
- Абстракции не должны зависеть от деталей. Детали должны зависеть от
  абстракций.

Вы также могли слышать о **Dependency Injection**. [Внедрение зависимостей](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) является связующим звеном между [IoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) и [DIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). Это [*один из способов*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control#Implementation_techniques) реализации инверсии управления.

---

Лучше почитайте английскую Вики про [IoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) и [DIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), там намного лучше все объяснено. Думаю, даже с помощью Гугл транслейта это будет полезнее, чем статьи на русской Вики.

В качестве русскоязычного источника могу порекомендовать статью [DI vs. DIP vs. IoC](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2014/11/di-vs-dip-vs-ioc.html) от Сергея Теплякова. Возможно он даже зайдет в этот вопрос и объяснит все как следует :).

Comment: а не объясните ли вы по теме - что такое "модули верхних уровней" и "модули нижних уровней", например в контексте web-фреймворка?

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр я бы сказал, что модули верхних уровней -- это модули, содержащие бизнес-логику и интерфейс, а модули нижних уровней -- модули, содержащие технические детали (например, обращение к БД или к стороннему сервису). Под "не должны зависеть" подразумеваются детали. Т.е. модуль бизнес-логики естественно использует модуль доступа к БД, но при этом в него не должны просачиваться детали имплементации (например, что это за БД и какой индекс надо использовать для выполнения запроса).

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр Нужно смотреть на число зависимоей модуля от других. Модули верхних уровней - те, которые ни от кого не зависят и от которых зависят другие модули. Модули нужнего уровня - те, которые зависят от большого числа других модулей.