# Обращение к экземпляру класса

Tags: java

Вопрос по теории Java. Есть два класса: класс А реализует JDesktopPane и класс В, реализует JInternalFrame. Класс В не внутренний и не вложенный относительно класса А. Как обратиться к экземпляру класса А из класса В? Сейчас я это реализую передачей экземпляра А в конструктор В. Это оптимальный способ или есть более удобные? 
Я к чему спрашиваю, предполагается ситуация, когда из класса В будет создаваться экземпляр класса С, а из него - экземпляр класса D. И так несколько раз. И из экземпляра класса, к примеру, Z я хочу получить доступ к экземпляру А. Значит ссылка на него должна передаваться каждый раз из конструктора в конструктор? 

Спасибо.

Comment: Это нормальный способ. Передача ссылки на другой объект как параметра конструктора, с точки зрения дизайна, обычно означает, что создаваемый объект (чей конструктор) не может существовать без этой ссылки.

Comment: @Igor оформите ответом?

Comment: @andreycha - запросто :)

Comment: @Artik стоит внести это уточнение в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного дополню ответ @Igor.

Да, это нормально. В вашем случае тип `A` является *зависимостью* для типа `B`.

Как уже было упомянуто, через конструктор обычно передаются обязательные зависимости. Необязательные зависимости, как правило, устанавливаются через свойства/set-методы.

В более сложных сценариях вы можете получать экземпляры типа `A` не напрямую, а посредством какого-то объекта (например, фабрики). В таком случае встает вопрос об обращении к самой фабрике -- способы решения те же самые.

При этом сам тип `B` может являться зависимостью для других типов и должен передаваться (внедряться) точно так же. В сложных приложениях такие цепочки могут быть достаточно большими, поэтому используют контейнеры, облегчающие управление зависимостями.

Полезно будет почитать про:

- инверсию управления (inversion of control, IoC)
- внедрение зависимостей (dependency injection, DI)
- контейнеры (IoC или DI контейнеры)

Источников множество. Можно начать с [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461814/) [сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499395/), продолжить Википедией, Гуглом и [блогами](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2014/11/di-vs-dip-vs-ioc.html).

Answer (score 2):

Это нормальный способ. Передача ссылки на другой объект как параметра конструктора, с точки зрения дизайна, обычно означает, что создаваемый объект (чей конструктор) не может существовать без этой ссылки.